# How do I overlay lines on each bar of a bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

Suppose I have a bar plot like

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl)))+geom_bar()
```

[image]

Now I want to overlay a horizontal line at count = 5,4,6 for cyl = 4,6,8 respectively.  Each line should span the width of the bar on which it's overlaid.  How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firs, put your data of counts in new data frame that have the same column name cyl as in mtcars.

```
df2<-data.frame(cyl=c(4,6,8),counts=c(5,4,6))
```

One way to add those lines is to use `geom_crossbar()` and set `y`, `ymin` and `ymax` to the same values of `counts`.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl)))+geom_bar()+
  geom_crossbar(data=df2,aes(x=factor(cyl),
                  y=counts,ymin=counts,ymax=counts),color="green")
```

The same can be achieved with `geom_errorbar()`.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl)))+geom_bar()+
  geom_errorbar(data=df2,aes(x=factor(cyl),
                    ymin=counts,ymax=counts),color="green")
```

[image]